# How to use eql? with more than one argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it any Ruby way to refactor following code:

```
class Season

  def initialize(name)
    raise ArgumentError unless name.eql?("spring") || name.eql?("winter") || name.eql?    ("autumn") || name.eql?("summer")
    @name = name
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, we can't use eql? method with several arguments.

Comment: Why are you using `eql?`?

Comment: I guessed that eql? and == do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a more readable approach:

```
class Season
  def initialize(name)
    ensure_valid(name)
    @name = name
  end

  private

  def valid_names
    ['spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter']
  end

  def ensure_valid(name)
    raise ArguementError unless valid_names.include?(name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Surprisingly I got false for this: `name = "autumn"; name == ("spring" || "winter" || "autumn" || "summer")`

Comment: hi Oleg - that was a mistake on my part as another user pointed out.  if you try the code as it is now, it should work.

Comment: Downvoted and closevoted the question because this answer is not equivalent to the OP's original code unless `eql?` is the same as `==`, in which case there is no clear reason to use the unusual `eql?`. And the OP has not explained the intent of using `eql?`.

Comment: Why would you make `valid_names` a method rather than just a list?!

Comment: how do you know that the list of valid names is going to stay constant over time?  this approach is more readable and more easily adaptable to future changes